# How to center the contents of an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using an HTML `<table>` and I want to align the text of `<td>` to the center in each cell.

How do I center align the text horizontally and vertically?

Answer (score 495, accepted):

Here is an example with CSS and inline `style` attributes:

```css
td 
{
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px;
}

#cssTable td 
{
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Text</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2h3xo9k/

**EDIT**: The `valign` attribute is deprecated in HTML5 and should not be used.

Comment: Isn't the `vertical-align:middle` supposed to be applied to the `tr` element?

Comment: If you put an `img` tag in the same `td` didnt work

Comment: @posfan12 TLDR: no. Explanation: `td` elements (under normal circumstances) have the same height as their parent `tr` element, so changing the vertical alignment css property of the `tr` element will do nothing at all. There is no "available" space above or below the `td` elements.

Answer (score 78):

The CSS to center text in your `td` elements is

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 54):

HTML in line styling example:

```html
<td style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'></td>
```

CSS file example:

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 41):

Try to put this in your CSS file.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```html
<td align="center" valign="center">textgoeshere</td>
```

Is the only correct answer imho, since you're working with tables which is old functionality most common used for e-mail formatting. So your best bet is to not use just style but inline style and known table tags.

Comment: `valign` is deprecated in HTML5. Do not use it. For email formatting, a `style` tag or an inline `style` attribute would be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Selector > child:

```css
.text-center-row>th,
.text-center-row>td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width='500px'>
  <tr class="text-center-row">
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-center-row">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can use inbuilt class

```
<table class="text-center align-middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to vertically align content (multi-line) in a list-table

```
.. list-table::
   :class: longtable
   :header-rows: 1
   :stub-columns: 1
   :align: left
   :widths: 20, 20, 20, 20, 20

   * - Classification
     - Restricted
     - Company |br| Confidential
     - Internal Use Only
     - Public
   * - Row1 col1
     - Row1 col2
     - Row1 col3 
     - Row1 col4
     - Row1 col5
```

Using theme overrides .css option  I defined:

```
.stub {
       text-align: left;
       vertical-align: top;
}
```

In the theme that I use 'python-docs-theme', the cell entry is defined as 'stub' class.  Use your browser development menu to inspect what your theme class is for cell content and update that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
td 
{
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px;
}

#cssTable td 
{
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Text</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

`<td align="center"valign="center">textgoeshere</td>`

[more on valign](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp)

Comment: valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: align attribute is not supported in HTML 5. You have to use CSS instead.