# how to add dynamic latitude and longitude to ifram in html table row

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, iframe

in angular.js i am trying to ifram google maps with the code

```
<tr><td><iframe id="myIframe" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{rfq.latitude}},{{rfq.longitude}}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe></td></tr>
```

but i am getting error for `{{rfq.latitude}} and {{rfq.longitude}}` how can I concatenate url string in iFrame in my Table Row

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: not loading map,
but when i statically add lat and lng it loads perfact
like
<tr><td><iframe id="myIframe" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.5434454,55.3342324&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe></td></tr>

Comment: want to use value from {{rfq.latitude}}

Comment: Are you sure properties `latitude` and `longitude` are available in the `rfq` object? How is it assigned?

Comment: yes its available

Comment: i am trying this like <td>{{rfq.latitude}}</td> its show me value 
but can not concatenate with ifram url

Answer (score 1):

You could try to sanitize the URL using Angular [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). Here is a quick pipe for it

**safe.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: "safe",
  pure: true
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: any): SafeResourceUrl {
    console.log(`Pipe Called!`);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  rfq = {
    latitude: 43.182233,
    longitude: -72.167288
  };
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe id="myIframe"
        [src]="'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+rfq.latitude+','+rfq.longitude+'&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed' | safe"
        width="100%" 
        height="450" 
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working example: [Stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qcfvyf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: getting this error
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safe' could not be found

Comment: You need to create the `safe` [pipe](https://angular.io/cli/generate#pipe) first with `ng generate pipe safe`. And replace the contents of `safe.pipe.ts` with contents in the answer.

Comment: i have created the file as you mention in answer, but not working

Comment: how can i put my map to center of the row.. currently its appearing at left, i want to give it to full widt

Comment: @ShoaibAnwar: That's a CSS specific issue and has multiple solutions. You could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8986260/6513921). Also if you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through their [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.